# If a microphone has an output voltage of 2.5mV @ 1Pa, what would its output voltage be when 98dB SPL is applied to the diaphragm?

Tags: decibel

Microphone  spec    sheets  specify a   microphone’s    sensitivity by  displaying  the voltage at  the output  of  the microphone  when    1   Pa  is  applied to  the diaphragm.      If  a   microphone  has an  output  voltage of  2.5mV   @   1Pa,    what    would   its output  voltage be  when    98dB    SPL is  applied to  the diaphragm?

Comment: if 2.5mV @ 1Pa at half the level of a jackhammer 2Pa = 100dB.spl @ 1m would be 5mV so 98 dB is 2 dB down from 5mV

Answer (score 0):

The reference pressure for dbSPL is 20 micro Pascal so 1 Pascal is roughly 94 dB SPL.  98 dB SPL is about 1.59 Pa and the output voltage of your microphone would be around 3.7 mV.

Comment: the answer is 3.7 mV?